# Can Jenkins send notification mail when somebody changes the Configure in the job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Can Jenkins send notification mail when somebody changes the Configure(e.g String Parameter, choice Parameter, Execute shell scripts or other stuff) in the job?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds partially supported through the Mail Watcher plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mail+Watcher+Plugin

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3032

Limitation is that you are notified about a changement, but you won't know what has been changed.

Comment: I'm glad it help. Could you accept the answer so we can close the question?

Comment: Would you be able to offer an example of pipeline dsl syntax for adding this config to a jenkinsfile ?